# "Expose yourself to contraction of"

Tags: phrase-usage

> Without following proper safety measures in your workplace, you can **expose yourself to contraction** of viruses easily.

Is it correct to say *expose [...] to contraction*?

Comment: *contraction* often means getting smaller, so this is ambiguous, at least. Better to use another verb or verbal noun, as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can speak of contracting a disease that is caused by a virus, but you don't contract a virus per se.

Your meaning could be expressed like this:

> By not following proper safety measures in your workplace
> ... you could [easily] expose yourself to a virus.
> or
> ... you could [easily] contract a viral disease.